# Find smallest and biggest number of an array with reduce function in javascript

Tags: javascript

Just a matter of curiosity. With the reduce function, we could easily find the smallest and the biggest number inside an array separately. Just like that:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,1,-1,6,7,8,9,10,2,11];
a.reduce(function(prev,cur,index,array){
    return prev > cur ? prev : cur;
}); // returns 11

a.reduce(function(prev,cur,index,array){
    return prev < cur ? prev : cur;
}); // returns -1
```

Given that, why this don't work?

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,1,-1,6,7,8,9,10,2,11];
var smallest = 0;
var biggest = 0;
a.reduce(function(prev,cur,index,array){
    smallest = prev < cur ? prev : cur;
    biggest =  prev > cur ? prev : cur;
});
console.log([smallest, biggest]); // prints [11,11]
```

Tested on repl.it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the following:

```
a.reduce(function(prev,cur,index,array){
    smallest = prev < cur ? prev : cur;
    biggest =  prev > cur ? prev : cur;
});
```

the function supplied to *reduce* has no return statement so it returns *undefined*. So after the first iteration, *prev* is set to *undefined*.

If either expression in the [abstract relational comparison algorithm](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5) is undefined, the expression returns *undefined* (see step 3.c), which evaluates to *false*. So from the second iteration onward, both *smallest* and *biggest* are set to *cur* and at the end they're both set to the last value in the array.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When I added a return statement with "smallest" variable, all things worked. Although  @zerkms answer worked like a charm (I've Tested, and I wanted to upvote it too, but it was deleted before I could do that), you pointed me right to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

While using reduce, you need to return something inside reduce, otherwise reduce forgets previous values.

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,1,-1,6,7,8,9,10,2,11];
var initial = {
  smallest: a[0],
  biggest: a[0]
};
var result = a.reduce((prev, cur) => {
  prev.smallest = prev.smallest < cur ? prev.smallest : cur;
  prev.biggest = prev.biggest > cur ? prev.biggest : cur;
  return prev;
}, initial);

console.log(result);
// Prints object as,
// { smallest: -1, biggest: 11 }
```

Comment: To build on this, if you just want a the highest or lowest number by itself (and from an array of objects, adjust it like so `a = [{x: 1}, {x: 2}, {x: 3}]; a.reduce((previous, current) => previous > current.x ? previous : current.x, 0);`

Answer (score 2):

Two problems.

First, the lambda parameter to `reduce` has no return value.  If you aren't going to return something, `reduce` is just `forEach` with more parameters that don't mean anything.

Second, at each element, you compare `cur` to `prev` instead of comparing `cur` to `biggest` and `smallest`.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is ancient but here is how to solve such issues using array reduce:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,1,-1,6,7,8,9,10,2,11];

var minNumber = a.reduce(function(prev,cur) {
    return prev < cur ? prev : cur;
}, +Infinity);

var maxNumber = a.reduce(function(prev,cur) {
    return prev > cur ? prev : cur;
}, -Infinity);
```

---

Personally I'd just use `Math.min/max`:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,1,-1,6,7,8,9,10,2,11];

Math.min(...a) // will give -1
Math.max(...a) // will give 11
```

Comment: maxNumber should be initialized with `-Infinity` instead